# Understanding tensor symbol with limits

Tags: summation, tensor-products, tensors

I'm newby in tensor mathematics and its various notations. [Here](https://jonathan-hui.medium.com/qc-appendix-for-the-shors-algorithm-1a1710b89883#f290) I found transition from summation to some kind of tensor $\otimes$ summation (or multiplication) with limits. I don't know this symbol in `Latex` or `MathJax` that's why I didn't write out it here in my question (sorry for that). I can just attach screen of it:

[image]

What does this symbol mean and how does it work?

Comment: $\bigotimes$ is `\bigotimes`

Comment: thank you!) but how can I set the limits for this symbol as in $\sum_0^N$ for example? and do you know, what does this operator do?

Comment: Just as with `sum`: Write `\bigotimes_{n = 0}^N`, for example.

Comment: @TravisWillse, thank you!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ ket vectors indexed by $l$. The $\bigotimes_{l=1}^n$ symbol simply means:

$$\bigotimes_{l=1}^n|k_l\rangle=|k_1\rangle\otimes\cdots \otimes |k_n\rangle$$

The exponential scalars will be pulled out of the $n$ fold tensor product, so I have elected to ignore them for ease of notation.

To explain the quantum mechanics notation a bit, whenever you have something like $|k_1\cdots k_n\rangle$, this is a stand in for the tensor product of the individual states $|k_l\rangle$.

Comment: thank you so much!)